# Prove that if $A \sim B$ and $C \sim D$ then $^{A} C \sim \ ^{B} D$. Is my proof correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This is the problem from "How to Prove It. A Structured Approach" by Danile. J. Velleman.

For any sets $A$ and $B$, the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$ is denoted $\ ^{A} B$.

That's my proof.

Since $A \sim B$ we have $f_{AB}: A \to B$ that is one-to-one and onto. Since $C\sim D$ we have $f_{CD}:C \to D$ that is one-to-one and onto. Also we have a function $h: A\times C \to B\times D$ that is also one-to-one and onto i.e. $A\times C \sim B\times D$. This function defined as follows $h(a,c) = (f_{AB}(a), f_{CD}(c))$.

Let $H:\ ^{A} C \to \ ^{B} D$ be defined as follows $H(X) = $ the image of $X$ under $h$. So $H(X) = \{ (b,d)\in B\times D | \exists (a,c) \in X : h(a,c) = (b,d) \}$.

Let $Y = H(g_{AC})$. Now we should prove that $Y$ is a function from $B$ to $D$. i.e. $Y \in \ ^{B}D$.

So let $b\in B$ then $\exists a\in A: f_{AB}(a) = b$. Also let $g_{AC}(a) = c$, $c \in C$. Since $(a,c) \in g_{AC}$ then $h(a,c) \in Y$. But $h(a,c) = (b, f_{CD}(c))$. So let $f_{CD}(c) = d \in D$. And we have for any $b\in B$ there is $d = (f_{CD}\circ g_{AC} \circ f_{AB}^{-1})(b)$ so that $(b,d) \in Y$.

Comment: "*Is* my proof correct?"

Comment: Yeah it looks fine, though you stould prove that H is a bijection.